# Angular Reactive Forms Async Validation using an Observable from Service

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm doing a web application in Angular 8.3.4. I have a form using Reactive Forms and I want to add Async Validation to make sure that the name entered is unique. I have read a lot of examples out there, but for some reason is not working for me.

Service

```
export class BrandService {
  brands: Observable<BrandId[]>;
}
```

Component

```
export class CreateNewComponent {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private brandService: BrandService
  ) {
    // Creates a form group
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6),
        CustomValidator.unique(this.brandService.brands)
      ])]
    });
  }
}
```

Custom validator

```
export class CustomValidator {

  static unique(brands: Observable<BrandId[]>) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {

      const name = control.value.toLowerCase();

      return brands.pipe(
        map(items => items.filter(b => b.name.toLowerCase() === name)),
        map(items => items.length ? {unique: false} : null)
      );

    };
  }

}
```

I'm passing the Observable of the service from the component to the CustomValidator. Right now, the control has: `status: "INVALID"`

By the way, what should I explicitly return in my `unique` method?

My goal is to know if the name already exists in the array of the Observable to return a control error.

Comment: an async validator must be implements AsyncValidator, see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-custom-async-validator. NOTE: you always can in submit call to your observable and show a message it's not unique

Answer (score 0):

The async validator should be passed in via another array (or on its own), something like

```
name: [
  '', 
  Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]), 
  () => CustomValidator.unique(this.brandService.brands)
]
```

Also notice that it is in a function, many of the examples I found early on used `bind` like [in this article](https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/), but I like using a function instead.

------Edit ------
Here is a working example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new',
  templateUrl: './new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new.component.css']
})
export class NewComponent {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private brandService: BrandService,
  ) {
    const brand = new BrandId();
    brand.name = 'abcdef';

    this.brandService.brands = of([brand]);
    // Creates a form group
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6),
      ]),
        (control) => CustomValidator.unique(this.brandService.brands, control)]
    });
  }
}

export class CustomValidator {
  static unique(brands: Observable<BrandId[]>, control: AbstractControl) {
    const name = control.value.toLowerCase();

    return brands.pipe(
      map(items => items.filter(b => b.name.toLowerCase() === name)),
      map(items => items.length ? { unique: false } : null)
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only change that I need? According to the answer of Eliseo above, I need to implement AsyncValidator, this implementation is required or with your solution is enough?

Comment: In my testing as long as you return null it won't show an error. The error object you return looks like it should work.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. Try returning {unique: true}. At that point you may want to rename from unique.

Comment: For some reason, is still not working for me. The control/form keeps `status: "INVALID"` all the time.

Comment: Hi my friend, I have tried your new solution, but, it's not working for me yet. The field doesn't fire up the error message, I cannot tell if the value entered is unique or not. I don't know what is happening.